# How to explain that the same answer was given before

Tags: phrase-request

A student out of the audience asks something similar to a question a lecturer answered previously in a dialogue with another student. What can the lecturer say in responce in this situation? Of course, I'm asking about idiomatic and colloquial phrases. Should the lecturer give the answer *in the present simple* or *in the present continuous*?

> The same [that I said before] is referring to your question too.
>
> What I said 5 minutes ago applies to your question too.

I also consider possibility of using verbs '**belong**', '**concern**', etc. Could you suggest something appropriate for this type of situations?

Comment: I would use the present simple, "applies". "What I said 5 minutes ago applies to your question too." Or "could be applied to ..", or "is applicable".

Comment: *What I said 5 minutes ago is [being] applied to your question too.* - this is actually the Passive Voice, and depicts a situation in which something is being actively applied (by someone) to your question "this very moment". A strange situation. (0:

Comment: "How do you know that his answer would be applied to this question in a week?" - A good question! I need to think about this. Still "my answer is applying to your question too" would look outlandish.

Comment: I tried to format your question to make it more understandable. What is your main concern? To pick the right verb? Or to select between simple present / progressive?

Comment: 'apply' is never used in present continuous like this. We say 'conditions apply' and not "conditions are applying".

Comment: **I want to ask about idiomatic phrases** - I will then abstain from answering, being a non-native speaker. I only can explain why **applying** would look strange in the stead of **applies**.

Comment: Oh, the teacher might just mark the student's question as "duplicate". :D

Comment: Seriously though, it kinda depends on the "mood" the teacher is in. If s\he is upset, s\he might make use of this: "If you were actually listening to what I was teaching five minutes ago, you would have found out I answered the very same question."

Comment: @MARamezani but the question is not the same but somewhat similar to the previous one.

Comment: That way, and with taking an average mood for the teacher into account, I see @A.Beth's third suggestion most applicable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use something like:

1: "What I said 5 minutes ago *applies* to your question too."

2: "What I said five minutes ago *answers* this question."

3: "I thought I answered that five minutes ago -- can you point me to where I need to clarify?"

Comment: thanks. Do you think the construction 'is being applied' is incorrect? Is it impossible to use the passive voice in the present continuous here?

Comment: "is being applied" means that it is *right now* in the *process* of being applied. So no, it would not be correct unless it's happening even as you speak. There are situation where that construction would work (e.g., "your car is being treated with the same process that I described 5 minutes ago, sir"), but this sentence is not one of them.

Comment: I'd vote for no. 3...